# Issues witht the bcp command when using variables

Tags: t-sql

The bcp commnad below gives NO errors

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select RecordType + PaymentYear from   CentersApp.dbo.IRS_TRecord"     
queryout "\\w2k3solomon\c$\IRS1099B\IRS_VENDORS.TXT"  -T -c -S SOLOMON'
```

However, when I use variables to do the same thing (see below), I am getting the error **`'bcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command`**

```
  declare @t nvarchar(200)
  declare @s nvarchar(1000)


   set @t = '"select RecordType + PaymentYear from CentersApp.dbo.IRS_TRecord"'
   set @s =  '''bcp ' + '"' +  @t + '"' +  '        queryout "\\w2k3solomon\c$\IRS1099B\IRS_VENDORS.TXT"  -T -c -S SOLOMON '''

   exec master..xp_cmdshell @s
```

Comment: I would recommend running `select @s` before running `xp_cmdshell` to make sure that you're forming the string correctly. If it looks okay, then copy it and paste it into the first example where variables are not used to see if it returns an error.

Comment: I have done that already. The string looks exactly identical to the first one

Comment: did you try removing the quotes wrapping the @s variable?  it's already a string so you shouldn't need to wrap it (ie 'bcp ' + ...)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I just noticed that the value of the variable `@t` starts and ends with quotation marks. Then additional quotation marks are included before and after when setting the value of `@s`.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was an extra set of double quotes and I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
set @s =  '''bcp ' + '"' +  @t + '"' +  '        queryout "\\w2k3solomon\c$\IRS1099B\IRS_VENDORS.TXT"  -T -c -S SOLOMON '''
```

to

```
set @s =  'bcp ' + '"' +  @t + '"' +  '        queryout "\\w2k3solomon\c$\IRS1099B\IRS_VENDORS.TXT"  -T -c -S SOLOMON '
```

it is stored in a string variable type so you don't need to use the quotes

Comment: It is not needed to concatenate 'bcp ' and '"' together. They can be part of the same string.  The same is true for '"' and 'queryout ...'.   For example `set @s =  'bcp "' +  @t + '"        queryout "\\w2k3solomon\c$\IRS1099B\IRS_VENDORS.TXT"  -T -c -S SOLOMON '` will improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was an extra set of double quotes and I removed it.